# Vuetity v-autocomplete and v-data-table are not working

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, sass, vuetify.js

Vue and Vuetify was working perfectly in my previous projects. But now in order to test some stuffs, I have tried to start a new project npm. I have added vuetify to my project with the command :

```
> vue add vuetify
```

The v-text-field and v-btn is working, however when I tried to use more complexe components such as v-autocomplete and v-data-table, I got

```
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                       4:46:43 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.sass

Syntax Error: SassError: Expected identifier.
   ╷
68 │       position: relative
   │                         ^
   ╵
  node_modules\vuetify\src\components\VSelect\VSelect.sass 68:25  root stylesheet


 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.sass 4:14-206 15:3-20:5 16:22-214
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSelect/VSelect.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete/index.js
 @ ./src/views/About.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.157:8082&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I have tried to change the version of sass-loader and sass and try to add/remove node-sass, without any great success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar error when trying to use v-select.
Other posts I've seen suggest doing `npm install sass@1.32.8`, but it didn't work for me.

Simply upgrading vuetify solved the problem.

```
yarn upgrade vuetify
```

if you are using npm, run instead

```
npm update vuetify
```

Comment: Thanks you this clarification. I will try to update if it happens again, for now I managed to get it working with  ```npm install sass@1.32.8``` before serving the project